# Why should a Drupal copy be extracted in the web directory?

Tags: files

I am trying to create a multi-site using [Set up a multisite](https://www.drupal.org/docs/getting-started/multisite-drupal/set-up-a-multisite), but I do not understand the reason for step 1.2.

Why should a Drupal copy be extracted in the web directory?

There doesn't seem to be anything written about this.

Comment: The more I look at those instructions the less sense they make. I understand why you are confused.

Comment: Web directory probably just means where your server will look for a website. Most of the time it's in a folder called `/var/www/html/web`. But it doesn't have to be. Wherever nginx/apache will look for your site will be referred to as the "web directory"

Answer (score 0):

That refers to installing Drupal in the ordinary way. Using the recommended install process to the directory referred to as “base-site”, which could have any name you want, there will be a subdirectory named “web” that you will reference in the virtual host configuration.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply. Above that point it already says Drupalshould be downloaded and installed. I was thinking that on point 1.2. it says to install it again in the 'web' directory of the main installation folder. I am already pretty familiar with the drupal structure and there's a directory called web and I thought it refers to that one. So I should not install Drupal again in '/var/www/base-site/web/here'   , right?

Comment: You install Drupal only once. There is only one instance of the Drupal codebase needed.

Comment: @cossinner Truly, [Overview of the process](https://www.drupal.org/docs/getting-started/multisite-drupal/set-up-a-multisite#s-overview-of-the-process) is a summary of how to set up a multi-site; the details are then given point-by-point in the next sections. That documentation page does not say Drupal must be installed twice.